# NodeJS/Nodemailer Can use nodemailer locally? Problem - Greeting never received

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, local, nodemailer

When i try to send mail using nodemailer in local network there is Error:

```
*Greeting never received
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\PI_TEAM\Desktop\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (C:\Users\PI_TEAM\Desktop\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:770:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PI_TEAM\Desktop\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:704:22)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  command: 'CONN'ork connection, the*
```

The same code working If I'm connected to wifi(global network).
The SMTP server is local. For example I can send mails using Command Prompt locally but using nodemailer - no.
Is nodemailer need global network to work ? How to use it locally?

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably the case of security certificate.
When you send it globally it get's the SSL certificate and sends the mail.
Try and use **ngrok** as well. If it sends the mail as well then it's the SSL certificate issue i.e `http` and `https`.

Comment: I cannot install ngrok - ngrok - error downloading binary Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain.

Comment: In that case try running `npm config set strict-ssl=false` and try again

Comment: i tried but it still doesnt work, this error is only when i try to install ngrok, when trying with another modules, its working